# Why the matrix (2d array) isn't showing properly when printing it

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wrote a tic tac toe game, it is not against the computer. In a nutshell, the user enters a location on the board (3X3) and that location is converted to `x` or `o` (depends on the turn of x and o). If x or o fills a column, row or a diagonal - it wins.

I'm faced with some problems in my code,
1. The matrix doesn't show up properly, it puts every chosen location in the same location.
2. The program starts with x as it should do, but skips o.

I would be happy if you'll explain where I did go wrong.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define COL 3
#define ROW 3

int validity(char board[][COL], int player,int row,int col);
void turns(char board[][COL],int player);
int win(char board[][COL]);
void printBoard(char board[][COL]);

/*
main will determine the turn of x and o until there is a victory 
in: none
out: 0
*/
int main(void)
{
    char board[ROW][COL] = { { 0 } };
    int player = 'o';
    do{
        if (player == 'x')
        {
            player = 'o';
            turns(board,player);
        }
        else if (player == 'o')
        {
            player = 'x';
            turns(board,player);
        }
    } while (win(board) == 0);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
/*this func will print the board
in: board
out: none
*/
void printBoard(char board[][COL])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            printf("%c ", board[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
/*
this func will assign 'x' or 'o' to the entered location on the board
in: the board and x or o
out: none
*/
void turns(char board[][COL],int player)
{
    int row = 0, col = 0;

    printf("It is %c turn's. \n", player);
    printf("Enter a location on the board: \n");

    scanf("%d", &board[row][col]);
    if (validity(board,player,row,col) == 1)
    {
        board[row][col] = player;
    }
    else
    {
        turns(board, player);
    }

    printBoard(board);
}
/*
this func will determine if x or o has won 
in: the board
out: 0 = noone has won
     1 = x or o has won
*/
int win(char board[][COL])
{
    int flag = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) // this loop will check if o or x won by filling a row
    {
        if (board[i][j] == 'x')
        {
            printf("X won!");
            flag = 1;
        }
        else if (board[i][j] == 'o')
        {
            printf("O won!");
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) // this loop will check if o or x won by filling a column 
    {
        if (board[i][j] == 'x')
        {
            printf("X won!");
            flag = 1;
        }
        else if (board[i][j] == 'o')
        {
            printf("O won!");
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    for (k = 0; k < COL; k++) // this loop will check if x or o won by filling a diagonal
    {
        if (board[k][k] == 'x')
        {
            printf("X won!");
            flag = 1;
        }
        else if (board[k][k] == 'o')
        {
            printf("O won!");
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}

/*this func will check the validity of a choice that the player has made (if the location is taken by o or x or not).
in: board, x / o, the location
out: 0 = the location is taken
     1 = the location is valid
*/
int validity(char board[][COL], int player,int row,int col)
{
    int check = 0;
    if (board[row][col] == 'o' && player == 'x' || board[row][col] == 'x' && player == 'o')
    {
        printf("Invalid choice.\n");
        check = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        check = 1;
    }
    return check;
}
```

Example for the output:
[image]

Comment: could you please dump a sample of your output to see what you mean? maybe a picture, I would like to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misktake while taking input of locations in `turns` function.

The function should be as follows

```
void turns(char board[][COL],int player)
{
  int row = 0, col = 0;

  printf("It is %c turn's. \n", player);
  printf("Enter a location on the board: \n");

  scanf("%d %d", &row,&col);
  if (validity(board,player,row,col) == 1)
  {
      board[row][col] = player;
  }
  else
  {
      turns(board, player);
  }

printBoard(board);
}
```

Your's was

```
int row=0,col=0;
scanf("%d",&board[row][col])
```

where row and column are always zero.